# Wordpress Portofolio Conditional Templating - functions php

Tags: categories, taxonomy

I'm trying to load some code depending on which portfolio category i am , but cant seem to get it quite right...
I've read that portfolio categories are called taxonomies, but don't know if thats right..
tried this code in my `functions.php` but crashed my whole site!

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'ava_auto_click');
function ava_auto_click(){
$the_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'portfolio_entries');
for ($i=0;$i< count($the_terms); ++$i) {
    var_dump($the_terms[$i]);
if($the_terms[$i] =="projects"){     
?>
<script>
    window.onload = function(){     
        var elem = document.querySelector('.wrap-filter').querySelectorAll('li')
        var event = new Event('click');
        document.getElementById('projects').classList.remove('none')
        elem[0].setAttribute("data-filter", ".offices, .retail, .residential, .stands, .cultural");
        elem[0].firstElementChild.setAttribute("data-filter", ".offices, .retail, .residential, .stands, .cultural");
        elem[1].classList.toggle('active')
        elem[1].querySelector('a').click();

    }
</script>
<?php

    }
    else { 


        ?>
        <script>
            window.onload = function(){     
                var elem = document.querySelector('.wrap-filter').querySelectorAll('li')
                var event = new Event('click');
                document.getElementById('projects').classList.remove('none')
                elem[1].classList.toggle('active')
                elem[1].querySelector('a').click();

            }
        </script>
        <?php
         }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!!

I think the main structure is right but the `if` and the `$the_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'portfolio_entries');` might be wrong

Comment: A "portfolio category" could just be a Core category, or could be a custom taxonomy - but also could be postmeta, just depends on how it was originally set up. So, your first step is to determine what type of data these portfolio categories actually are. You can see if it's a Core Category by logging in, hovering over the Posts menu, and clicking Categories. If the portfolio categories are there, they're Core Categories. If not, search through your theme or plugin's code to find a call to `register_taxonomy()` to confirm whether they're custom taxonomies.

Comment: Alright will try that! Meanwhile i just did the if statement with the current url of the page instead of the porfolio category.